# The smallest number of boxes to buy to have probability at least 1/2 of collecting all pictures

Tags: probability

Let's suppose that every time I buy a box of chips I get a picture. Over some time I buy $m\ge n$ boxes of chips. How can I find the smallest $m$ (number of boxes bought) so that the probability I'll get all pictures of a set of $n$ pictures to be $\ge 1/2$?

Result should be close to $m =n\ln(n) + n\ln(2)$, but I should find it using another method.

Comment: This looks like a median version of the coupon collector's problem. The probability is $\frac{n!}{n^m}S_2(m,n)$. You seem to have used the [Erdős and Rényi result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations), but if I have not miscalculated for moderate $n$ the $\ln(2) $ coefficient seems a little too large:  for example for $n=26$ I think $m\ge 94$ is sufficient while your expression might suggest something nearer $103$.

Comment: S2(m,n) matters in formula or just n!/m^n? and if it matters it's something about stirling numbers?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a median version of the coupon collector's problem.

You seem to have used the [Erdős and Rényi result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Extensions_and_generalizations), that $$\operatorname{P}(T < n\log n + cn) \to e^{-e^{-c}}, \ \  \text{as}  \ n \to \infty$$ but if so you have a slight error: trying to solve $\frac12=e^{-e^{-c}}$ gives $c=-\log_e(\log_e(2))$ rather than $+\log_e(2)$.  The correct $$m \approx n\log_e(n) - n\log_e(\log_e(2))$$ turns out to be very good.

The actual probability is $$\frac{n!}{n^m}S_2(m,n)$$ where $S_2(m,n)$ gives [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), and so one possibility would be to check a large possible number of possible $m$s for each $n$ and find which provide an optimal solution.

But given we have an approximation for $m$ given $n$, it seems more sensible to round that to the nearest integer and then check the numbers one above and below. Here are the values for the first $100$ values of $n$: in $87$ cases rounding the approximation gives the best answer and in the other $13$ cases going one higher does.

```
   n  approx_m  round-1 prob   round_m prob   round+1 prob
   1   0.3665129  -1  0.0000000    0 0.0000000   1 1.0000000
   2   2.1193202   1  0.0000000    2 0.5000000   3 0.7500000
   3   4.3953756   3  0.2222222    4 0.4444444   5 0.6172840
   4   7.0112291   6  0.3808594    7 0.5126953   8 0.6229248
   5   9.8797542   9  0.4270694   10 0.5225472  11 0.6063636
   6  12.9496343  12  0.4378157   13 0.5138582  14 0.5828453
   7  16.1869615  15  0.4339188   16 0.4977198  17 0.5569727
   8  19.5676357  19  0.4783476   20 0.5305582  21 0.5792723
   9  23.0736375  22  0.4576533   23 0.5044271  24 0.5487460
  10  26.6909801  26  0.4789855   27 0.5196335  28 0.5583032
  11  30.4084901  29  0.4544382   30 0.4919362  31 0.5279911
  12  34.2170348  33  0.4656260   34 0.4993248  35 0.5318211
  13  38.1090096  37  0.4722147   38 0.5028825  39 0.5325431
  14  42.0779835  41  0.4755268   42 0.5037219  43 0.5310680
  15  46.1184468  45  0.4764483   46 0.5025865  47 0.5280045
  16  50.2256263  49  0.4755917   50 0.4999897  51 0.5237732
  17  54.3953465  53  0.4733921   54 0.4962959  55 0.5186731
  18  58.6239242  58  0.4917706   59 0.5129218  60 0.5335808
  19  62.9080861  62  0.4866108   63 0.5066811  64 0.5263255
  20  67.2449039  66  0.4809655   67 0.5000733  68 0.5188116
  21  71.6317425  71  0.4931925   72 0.5111144  73 0.5286907
  22  76.0662182  75  0.4861118   76 0.5032926  77 0.5201712
  23  80.5461641  80  0.4953923   81 0.5116312  82 0.5275874
  24  85.0696020  84  0.4874501   85 0.5030991  86 0.5184994
  25  89.6347186  89  0.4945974   90 0.5094807  91 0.5241309
  26  94.2398459  93  0.4861442   94 0.5005446  95 0.5147389
  27  98.8834442  98  0.4917014   99 0.5054669 100 0.5190387
  28 103.5640881 103  0.4963200  104 0.5095089 105 0.5225161
  29 108.2804538 107  0.4873024  108 0.5001276 109 0.5127910
  30 113.0313091 112  0.4908958  113 0.5032309 114 0.5154137
  31 117.8155039 117  0.4938348  118 0.5057198 119 0.5174617
  32 122.6319623 122  0.4962003  123 0.5076707 124 0.5190064
  33 127.4796759 126  0.4868528  127 0.4980610 128 0.5091485
  34 132.3576971 131  0.4886296  132 0.4994761 133 0.5102086
  35 137.2651344 136  0.4899861  137 0.5004964 138 0.5108991
  36 142.2011469 141  0.4909687  142 0.5011656 143 0.5112611
  37 147.1649408 146  0.4916178  147 0.5015222 148 0.5113307
  38 152.1557651 151  0.4919688  152 0.5015992 153 0.5111391
  39 157.1729081 156  0.4920525  157 0.5014258 158 0.5107137
  40 162.2156950 161  0.4918961  162 0.5010277 163 0.5100786
  41 167.2834845 166  0.4915235  167 0.5004274 168 0.5092550
  42 172.3756666 171  0.4909560  172 0.4996450 173 0.5082616
  43 177.4916606 176  0.4902124  177 0.4986980 178 0.5071152
  44 182.6309124 182  0.4976023  183 0.5058305 184 0.5139914
  45 187.7928935 187  0.4963721  188 0.5044209 189 0.5124059
  46 192.9770986 192  0.4950198  193 0.5028981 194 0.5107159
  47 198.1830445 197  0.4935569  198 0.5012727 199 0.5089313
  48 203.4102687 202  0.4919935  203 0.4995545 204 0.5070611
  49 208.6583277 208  0.4977519  209 0.5051134 210 0.5124216
  50 213.9267963 213  0.4958727  214 0.5030955 215 0.5102676
  51 219.2152662 218  0.4939241  219 0.5010140 220 0.5080558
  52 224.5233452 224  0.4988749  225 0.5057916 226 0.5126612
  53 229.8506562 229  0.4966837  230 0.5034804 231 0.5102322
  54 235.1968362 234  0.4944453  235 0.5011265 236 0.5077652
  55 240.5615358 240  0.4987345  241 0.5052641 242 0.5117520
  56 245.9444182 245  0.4963080  246 0.5027326 247 0.5091175
  57 251.3451587 250  0.4938506  251 0.5001739 252 0.5064594
  58 256.7634440 256  0.4975911  257 0.5037806 258 0.5099330
  59 262.1989715 261  0.4949869  262 0.5010836 263 0.5071450
  60 267.6514490 267  0.4983709  268 0.5043441 269 0.5102828
  61 273.1205939 272  0.4956445  273 0.5015324 274 0.5073873
  62 278.6061329 278  0.4987117  279 0.5044854 280 0.5102268
  63 284.1078018 283  0.4958836  284 0.5015786 285 0.5072427
  64 289.6253443 289  0.4986683  290 0.5042573 291 0.5098161
  65 295.1585124 294  0.4957559  295 0.5012719 296 0.5067590
  66 300.7070657 300  0.4982875  301 0.5037050 302 0.5090941
  67 306.2707712 305  0.4953054  306 0.5006549 307 0.5059775
  68 311.8494026 311  0.4976097  312 0.5028673 313 0.5080985
  69 317.4427403 316  0.4945701  317 0.4997644 318 0.5049335
  70 323.0505714 322  0.4966695  323 0.5017778 324 0.5068615
  71 328.6726886 328  0.4986322  329 0.5036576 330 0.5086589
  72 334.3088909 333  0.4954970  334 0.5004656 335 0.5054111
  73 339.9589824 339  0.4972858  340 0.5021767 341 0.5070448
  74 345.6227730 345  0.4989560  346 0.5037717 347 0.5085652
  75 351.3000776 350  0.4957494  351 0.5005138 352 0.5052568
  76 356.9907158 356  0.4972712  357 0.5019648 358 0.5066376
  77 362.6945124 362  0.4986893  363 0.5033145 364 0.5079193
  78 368.4112963 367  0.4954305  368 0.5000090 369 0.5045679
  79 374.1409011 373  0.4967212  374 0.5012351 375 0.5057298
  80 379.8831644 379  0.4979208  380 0.5023721 381 0.5068047
  81 385.6379281 385  0.4990338  386 0.5034244 387 0.5077967
  82 391.4050378 390  0.4957149  391 0.5000643 392 0.5043960
  83 397.1843429 396  0.4967242  397 0.5010161 398 0.5052907
  84 402.9756964 402  0.4976568  403 0.5018928 404 0.5061120
  85 408.7789551 408  0.4985162  409 0.5026981 410 0.5068634
  86 414.5939786 414  0.4993058  415 0.5034351 416 0.5075481
  87 420.4206304 419  0.4959351  420 0.5000287 421 0.5041068
  88 426.2587767 425  0.4966444  426 0.5006880 427 0.5047163
  89 432.1082868 431  0.4972914  432 0.5012863 433 0.5052662
  90 437.9690332 437  0.4978789  438 0.5018264 439 0.5057593
  91 443.8408909 443  0.4984094  444 0.5023108 445 0.5061978
  92 449.7237378 449  0.4988854  450 0.5027419 451 0.5065843
  93 455.6174545 455  0.4993092  456 0.5031219 457 0.5069208
  94 461.5219241 461  0.4996829  462 0.5034530 463 0.5072096
  95 467.4370322 466  0.4962673  467 0.5000087 468 0.5037372
  96 473.3626668 472  0.4965879  473 0.5002886 474 0.5039766
  97 479.2987182 478  0.4968634  479 0.5005244 480 0.5041728
  98 485.2450791 484  0.4970957  485 0.5007178 486 0.5043278
  99 491.2016443 490  0.4972865  491 0.5008708 492 0.5044431
 100 497.1683107 496  0.4974374  497 0.5009847 498 0.5045203
```

Comment: Where did the n!/(n^m)*S2(m,n) come from?

Comment: @jandawl - One way is to take the definition of $S_2(m,n)$: the number of ways to partition a set of $m$ objects into $n$ non-empty subsets.  But here you want to count compositions rather than partitions as the individual pictures are identifiable so multiply by $n!$.  Finally you want a probability so divide byt the total number of equally likely outcomes $n^m$

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks!