# Get over 50% chance to get N things

Tags: probability

At each draw, you take 1 of N things (I'll call them coupons) (Uniformly distributed) with replacement and you take note of which ones you have seen so far. Determine the number n such that after n draws you have at least a 50% chance of seeing all different coupons. Essentially I am asking for a formula in terms of and N for n.

This is a problem similar to the coupon collector problem. Thank you in advance!

So far I tried base examples to derive a formula and prove it with PMI with no luck. I reposted this problem after making some edits to the original (which was put on hold for some reason).

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a particularly convenient closed form, but you could if you so choose approach with matrices and markov chains (states being the number of distinct coupons seen so far ignoring zero) and look for one more than the smallest power of the matrix such that the top right entry is greater than $0.5$.  For example for $N=4$ one has transition matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1&\frac{1}{4}&0&0\\0&\frac{3}{4}&\frac{2}{4}&0\\0&0&\frac{2}{4}&\frac{3}{4}\\0&0&0&\frac{1}{4}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and through trial and error we see $n$ will be $7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my idea and finding the first six entries in the sequence: 1,2,5,7,10,13,... and then searching http://oeis.org yielded the result [A073593](http://oeis.org/A073593).

There is no convenient formula listed, but according to the references it is hypothesized that it is asymptotic to $n(\log(n)+\frac{1}{e})$

The method suggested used to generate the list is similar to the one I describe above.  Their specific suggestion is more efficient in that they only care about keeping track of the far right column, or equivalently worded, they search for the least $n$ for which $A^nv$ has top entry greater than $\frac{1}{2}$, but instead of calculating in the order $(A(A(\dots(A))\dots)v$ they calculate instead in the order $(A(A(\dots(Av))\dots)$, requiring less memory and computation time.

Specific pseudocode on oeis: `a(n)=v=vector(n+1); k=1; v[n]=1.0; while(v[1]<0.5, k++; for(i=1, n, v[i]=v[i]*(n+1-i)/n+v[i+1]*i/n)); k`

Comment: +1 for the OEIS link. The $\frac{1}{e} \approx 0.367879$ looks too high: for $552 \le n \le 1000$ (the highest value shown in OEIS), the figure is lower than $0.367$.  I believe the asymptotic result is more likely to be $n(\log(n)-\log(\log(2)))$ where $-\log(\log(2)) \approx +0.3665129$ using an Erdős and Rényi result as discussed in an earlier question http://math.stackexchange.com/a/978950/6460