# Negative Log inside Negative Log

Tags: functions, logarithms

Is there a name for a function which is like $f(x)=-\log(-\log(x))$ where $0<x<1$?

Or, is there any name for this function $g(x)=x+\log(\frac{1}{x})$ where $0<x$?

Exchanging $x=-\log k$ in $g(x)$ gives $f(k)$ and I would like to know about those functions any deeper, but I am having trouble searching about them. If there are any specific name or related function that I can search for, I will be very glad to know.

Comment: it should be called loggy log

Comment: It is the inverse of the Erdős-Rényi approximation $e^{-e^{-x}}$ related to the coupon-collector's distribution: see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1155770/6460 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/978950/6460

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first function corresponds to the inverse of the [standard cumulative Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) and occurs in extreme value statistics. In statistics, the inverse of a cumulative distribution is also called a [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function). So, that makes it the standard Gumbel quantile function.

Other than that, I cannot see a use for devoting special attention to this function, in any case not at the analysis level, as it is just a composite function and the interesting function from that point of view is just the logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

this function completely depends on the base which we are taking for -log(x) because log is defined for positive values
$$ -\log(x) > 0 $$
$$ \log(x) < 0  $$
as x lies between 0 to 1

then base of $\log(x)$ should lie between 1 to infinity(1 not included)
this is true only when it is not mentioned that base is 'e'

Comment: When it's not specified $\log = \ln$

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace In my half-century of reading and working in various flavors of science and engineering, log was assumed to be base 10 and ln was natural log. *Of course this is Math SE* and that makes a difference - if no base is given, it is assumed to be $e$ no matter how log is spelled.  I added a note at the top of the answer to try to address this. There may be something here of value to future readers.

Comment: I agree with you, but I think it is quite common for the Anglo-Saxon math community tu use $\log$ instead of $\ln$. For me it was also the base $10$ log but I got used to it… Informaticians tend to use $\log$ as well since they only need it up to proportionality and for basis decomposition.

Comment: ok i understood your point , i am learning how to use math SE so i dont know what exactly to do